# How to display dropdown in breadcrumb with Primeng?

Tags: angular, primeng

In primeng breadcrumbs we can display items only , is there a way to display dropdown on item when clicked ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way to do it with the primeng Breadcrumb component. It doesn't use custom templates for rendering the items and the input for the items is of type `MenuItem[]` (I pasted the `MenuItem` interface below).

You can style the items but not change their core structure, which is basically just an icon and/or label that can also navigate to another page when clicked.

```
interface MenuItem {
    label?: string;
    icon?: string;
    command?: (event?: any) => void;
    url?: string;
    items?: MenuItem[];
    expanded?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    visible?: boolean;
    target?: string;
    escape?: boolean;
    routerLinkActiveOptions?: any;
    separator?: boolean;
    badge?: string;
    tooltip?: string;
    tooltipPosition?: string;
    badgeStyleClass?: string;
    style?:any;
    styleClass?:string;
    title?: string;
    id?: string;
    automationId?: any;
    tabindex?: string;
    routerLink?: any;
    queryParams?: { [k: string]: any };
    fragment?: string;
    queryParamsHandling?: QueryParamsHandling;
    preserveFragment?: boolean;
    skipLocationChange?: boolean;
    replaceUrl?: boolean;
    state?: {
        [k: string]: any;
    }
    tooltipOptions?: {
        tooltipLabel?: string;
        tooltipPosition?: string;
        tooltipEvent?: string;
        appendTo?: any;
        positionStyle?: string;
        tooltipStyleClass?: string;
        tooltipZIndex?: string;
        escape?: boolean;
        disabled?: boolean;
        positionTop?: number;
        positionLeft?: number;
        showDelay?: number;
        hideDelay?: number;
        life?: number;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer already said - NO build-in functionality but

since the PrimeNG has MIT License you can extend the [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.ts) and add dropdown functionality as you want